# CSS: Override parent element style

Tags: html, css

Sometime back when I was googling, I came across an HTML menu with a nice animation. I decided to use the menu in one of my projects.

On normal condition, the menu looks like [image]

The original menu came with no sub-menus. I have added the sub-menu to meet my project need.
On hover, the menu looks like:-

[image]

And finally, the dropdown menu looks like this:
[image]

As you can see that in the last image, there are some unnecessary yellow lines appearing in the sub-menus. I think it's happening because the child elements inheriting the style of their parent.

I have been trying to disable/override it by writing explicit class for the child element but no success at all. I have a workable knowledge of CSS. I want to write such CSS that it would remove the unwanted yellow lines as highlighted in the 3rd image.

```css
.cl-effect-14 a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 46px;
}

.cl-effect-14 a::before,
.cl-effect-14 a::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 44px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #F9DB55;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cl-effect-14 a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:hover::after,
.cl-effect-14 a:focus::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:focus::before {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
}


/*****my code******/

ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 100%;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}

ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

.links {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transform: none;
}

.links::before {
  transform: none;
}

.links::after {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav cl-effect-14">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="typo.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Laptops</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Monitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Printers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Can someone please help me with CSS to remove those unwanted yellow lines. Thanks in advance.

Resources:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
<!--web-fonts-->
 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,700,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Prata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--//web-fonts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure your code snippet is working as intended

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Rolv. Please ignore the 'Run Code snippet' because it would not work. I approved the suggested Edit without having a good look at it. Please study my code and hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Ah your code uses bootstrap so without it your code won't render properly

Comment: yes, i have not put unnecessary codes.

Comment: The bootstrap would be necessary though, so we can see the same layout you see

Comment: Now I have included the resources.

Comment: Ah, you have them all locally. I'll post an answer but I'm probably using a different bootstraup so let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the main problem that you want solved is the yellow lines on the dropdown `a` elements. Those are happening because of the way the css for the navbar effects is written. For example:

```
.cl-effect-14 a::before
```

This means that ANY `a` tag withing an element with class `cl-effect-14` will get these changes, so this would include your `a` tags in the dropdown, as the dropdown has a parent with that class.

Now, this solution is not ideal, but you can use the css `:not()` selector to just specify that you don't want those effects to apply to `a` tags with the `links` class. So, the css turns into this:

```
.cl-effect-14 a {
  margin: 0 3px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 46px;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 44px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #F9DB55;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::after,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::before {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Note that I didn't add the `:not` selector to the first section as for some reason that was messing with the layout on the JsFiddle I was playing with. You'll have to let me know if this works for you though, as I probably didn't use the same bootstrap version as you. I added a margin to it as well so it looks more like the images you shared

I also changed your `.links` css to this:

```
.dropdown .links {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

As for some reason the `text-decoration` attribute was not being applied so I just added specificity.

The final code for me then looks like this (click `full page` to expand):

```css
.cl-effect-14 a {
  margin: 0 3px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 46px;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 44px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #F9DB55;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links)::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::after,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):hover::before,
.cl-effect-14 a:not(.links):focus::before {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%);
}


/*****my code******/

ul li ul.dropdown {
  min-width: 100%;
  /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}

ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown .links {
  color: black;
  background: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav cl-effect-14">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="typo.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Laptops</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Monitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Printers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

The dropdown is still off center but that's a whole other problem, if it's the same for you you could maybe post another question about it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Your solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks for all the help.